# Remove a specific item from an array of objects Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi All i am building a clone service desk system using React and materialUI I am having issues with removing specific items from an array of objects when the user clicks on it. I have tried to use updatedRow.splice(index,1) but this just removes the last object added to the array and not a specific object. I am trying to remove it based on the ticketID property I have tried to use the array method indexof to console log the specific index of the object but it just returns -1 meaning the item is not in the array when its displaying on the screen. The function should filter and only keep the items which havent been selected based on if the condition is true and remove what is true then should call Setrows to update what is on the screen. Could someone explain exactly what I am doing wrong here see code below...

```
 /// original array to populated with data 

 let row = [];
 const [rows, setRows] = useState(row);

 const formDataHandler = ({ desc, option }) => {
 const data = {
 description: desc,
 priority: option,
 lastUpdate: Date.now(),
 ticketID:shortid.generate()

 };

setRows([...rows, data]);
console.log(rows);
};

/// delete row function 

 const removeTicket = (index)=> {

 let updatedRow = rows;

// updatedRow.splice(index,1)

console.log(updatedRow.filter(index => ticketID !== index.id? ))

setRows([...updatedRow])



/// returned 

        <Container maxWidth="md">
  <Grid>
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Description</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Priority</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Last update</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Ticket ID</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.length>0?rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.ticketID}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.description}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.priority}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.lastUpdate}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.ticketID}</TableCell>

              <TableCell>
                <IconButton onClick={removeTicket} aria-label="delete" color="primary">
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          )):null}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </Grid>
  <FormDialog formData={formDataHandler} />
  {JSON.stringify(rows)}
</Container>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `ticketID` to your `IconButton`'s `onClick` handler:

```
<IconButton 
  onClick={() => removeTicket(row.ticketID)} 
  aria-label="delete" 
  color="primary"
>
  <DeleteIcon />
</IconButton>
```

And update your handler where you can create a new array using the `.filter()` method:

```
const removeTicket = (ticketID)=> {
  setRows(rows.filter(item => ticketID !== item.ticketID)
}
```

This `rows.filter()` returns every element where the `ticketID` is not the same as the one you passed down.

Comment: Thank you so the issue was I wasnt passing the ticketid property down into the handler such a basic mistake by myself. thanks for the help really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you know index that will be removed you can use `Array.prototype.slice` and
the logic is disconsider the element at index.

So, you will have to add the `index` as second param in your map function and change the `onClick` on `IconButton` to `() => removeTicket(index)`.

Your remove function will contains the following snippet:

```
setRows(prevRows => [
  ...prevRows.slice(0, index),
  ...prevRows.slice(index + 1)
]);
```

If you need the ticketId to make a call to an api you can get it through index `rows[index]` or by passing it in the onClick function `() => removeTicket(row.ticketID, index)`

Comment: yeah thanks for this I know understand the issue came from me not passing the param into the handler thank you so much for the help